# How do I pull text from an text field in kivy using a second screen?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I've recently started learning python and kivy, and for some reason I keeping getting

`AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__`'

Currently the code I have is simply for testing this, and I know other similar posts exist but I've followed the things they're doing to fix it and I keep getting the same error.

**This part is the text.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_file('text.kv')


# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class WritingScreen(Screen):
    pass


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(WritingScreen(name='Write'))
screens = [Screen(name='Title {}'.format(i)) for i in range(2)]




class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

    def write(self):
        sm.current = 'Write'

    def process(self):
        text = self.root.ids.input.text
        print("Hello")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**and here is my Text.kv file**

```
<MenuScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Write'
            on_press: app.write()
            size_hint: .3, .2
            background_color: 1, 2, 1, 1
            pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .4}
<WritingScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: input
            hint_text: "Ello There... Yaren't supposed to be here yet..."
            size_hint: .8, .1
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y': 0.9}
        Button:
            text: 'print'
            on_press: app.process()
            size_hint: .2, .1
            pos_hint: {'x':.8, 'y': .8}
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
            size_hint: .2, .1
            pos_hint: {'x':.8, 'y': .9}
```

Again I am so sorry if this is a repeated issue, but every post I've tried hasn't worked for me. Thank you for all the help, I'm still a beginner, and would appreciate any tips! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your line in the `process()` method:

```
text = self.root.ids.input.text
```

is trying to use the `input` `id` as though it was in the `ids` of the `root` (which is the `ScreenManager`), but `ids` dictionaries are set up in the root of `kv` rule where they are defined. So the `input` `id` is in the `ids` of the `WritingScreen`. To access the `ids` of the `WritingScreen`, you can change that line of code to something like:

```
text = self.root.get_screen('Write').ids.input.text
```